# Unable to set up SSL for public use. Possible port issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-7, https, windows-server-2008

I have a website hosted on IIS 7, Windows Server 2008, on Amazon server I think.

SSL certificate is set up and when browsing from the server everything works fine(except for the warning stating that the ssl is not registered for the domain(think that is because I was browsing using IP address instead of actual host name)). But publicly only http works. If I try accessing https, I get The connection has timed out. Same goes when domain name is set up and when using only IP.

I tried disabling windows firewall, and ran netstat which shows port 443 listening(I think, it was listed with local addresses as 0.0.0.0 and [::], but no foreign address shows port 443). I also ran netsh which lists certificate on port 443. When using http://www.adminkit.net/telnet.aspx I get 
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IpAddress:443"

Is there something I am missing? Any suggestion is really welcome. Also, could it be related to certificate itself? The certificate supplied didn't work at first and had to be converted to pfx using openssl.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have to ask your question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from ServerFault.com. Thanks to Marthijn for pointing me there.

Problem was that the website was hosted on Amazon EC2. Turns out there are server instance setting that needed to be edited so I had to go to amazon console, edit security group attached to the server instance and enable inbound traffic for port 443.